# Why is the li3 HTML helper not generating the correct path some of the time?

Tags: error-handling, helper, lithium

### Question

In the `'default'` layout for my Lithium install I have the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->html->script(array('jquery-1.7.1-dev.js')); ?>
```

For all normal requests (e.g. `/path/to/framework/users/login`, where `Users` is a model and there is a `UsersController::login` method) this is rendered correctly as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/framework/js/jquery-1.7.1-dev.js"></script>`
```

However, in views that are rendered by my error handling code the `/path/to/framework` is omitted and it is rendered as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1-dev.js"></script>
```

**Why is the helper not rendering the path correctly in this case?**

---

### Error-handling approach

My error handling approach is based on a number of online tutorials. In `config/bootstrap/errors.php` I have:

```
$exampleConditions = array('type' => 'Exception');
ErrorHandler::apply('lithium\action\Dispatcher::run', $exampleConditions, function($info, $params) {
    return ErrlogsController::handleError($info, $params);
});
ErrorHandler::run();
```

In the `ErrlogsController` class I have:

```
public static function handleError($info, $params) {
    // (Code to save error info to DB omitted from example)
    $view = new View(array(
        'paths' => array(
            'template' => '{:library}/views/{:controller}/{:template}.{:type}.php',
            'layout'   => '{:library}/views/layouts/{:layout}.{:type}.php'
        )
    ));
    return $view->render('all', array(), array(
        'template' => '404',
        'controller' => 'errlogs',
        'layout' => 'default',
        'type' => 'html'
    ));
}
```

I have code dived as deep as `lithium\template\view\Renderer::applyHandler` and the `File` adapter which do the actual rendering to try and understand this behaviour, and I have also tried adding an `'elements'` key to the `'paths'` array for `$view` but I am a bit stuck. Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.

---

### Background

The below two links show how to use `ErrorHandler::apply` function (as in above code) and also `ErrorHandler::config`. Both use the same approach as in the above code to render a view, and the first is also tangentially interesting to this post though because it also shows how to handle different types of errors differently.

- [Example one - masom](http://masom.posterous.com/handling-404-and-uncatched-exceptions-in-lith)
- [Example two - Lithium wiki](http://li3.me/docs/manual/handling-http-requests/controllers.wiki) - shows how to use the `ErrorHandler::apply` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components of the framework get their application base path information from the `Request` object, which the `View` class delegates to its helpers, unless of course it hasn't received it itself.

In your case, you could either pass it in the `'request'` key to `View`'s constructor, or update to a more modern version of error handling code, as per this: https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework/blob/master/app/config/bootstrap/errors.php